# Pair<L, R> in Groovy

Tags: groovy

Does Groovy support Pairs (e.g. from Java or C++)? If not, what would be a good way to get around this?

Comment: I assume you have written the Pair class?

Comment: Please give us some information on exactly what a 'pair' / 'Pair' is in your question.

Answer (score 16):

Groovy supports pairs using the class `Tuple2`.

A small example of using `Tuple2`:

```
def m = [a: new Tuple2(1, 2)]

m.b = new Tuple2('1', '2')

assert m.a.first == 1
assert m.a.second == 2

assert m.b.first == '1'
assert m.b.second == '2'
```

Also you can achieve more or less the same using `Map` as the value:

```
def n = [a: [first: 1, second: 2]]
n.b = [first: '1', second: '2']

assert n.a.first == 1
assert n.a.second == 2

assert n.b.first == '1'
assert n.b.second == '2'
```

Answer (score 9):

Groovy has a Tuple2 class as [Gergely's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39423655/217324) states.

However, there's an alternative to returning a Pair or tuple that may be easier; Groovy supports a feature called [multiple assignment](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_multiple_assignment), where you can assign the members of an array or list to different variables:

```
groovy:000> (a, b) = [1, 2]
===> [1, 2]
groovy:000> a
===> 1
groovy:000> b
===> 2
```

The variables don't have to have the same type.

So you can return a list with two entries from a method call, and let the caller assign them to different variables, without having to involve any kind of specialized container like a Pair or Tuple2 where you'd have to unpack the values from it.

If you want a well-defined contract with explicit names, then go with your own class. Alternatively use a Map so you can at least use the keys to assign names to the different things being returned.

Using a Tuple2 or Pair is as order-sensitive as using multiple assignment, is zero improvement with respect to naming, and adds extra boilerplate code to pack and unpack.

Answer (score 1):

There is a widely used `Pair` abstraction in Apache Commons Lang v3 (gradle coordinates `'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:+'`). The class signature looks like this:

```
package org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple;
public abstract class Pair<L, R> implements Map.Entry<L, R>, Comparable<Pair<L, R>>, Serializable
```

If you include this library in your build , and import the class you can use the static method `Pair.of(left,right)` to create instances. From a Groovy perspective, this object has property pairs `left` and `right`, or alternately `key` and `value` since the class implements `Map.Entry`.

Sample Groovy usage:

```
def p = Pair.of("hello", "world")
assert p.left == "hello"
assert p.right == "world"
assert p.key == "hello"
assert p.value == "world"
```

AFAIK, there is no `Pair` class in the Java API (verified [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html)), so any Java code that you have seen with `Pair` objects probably uses the same Apache Commons dependency.